# WordPress некорректный перенес сайта с локалки на боевой сервер

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! подскажите плиз, wordpress при переносе с локального сервера на боевой, слетели стили(не везде) и нет хедера и футера ну и так по мелочи всякие штуки не работают. Тему сам доводил до ума по купленному заказчиком шаблону! Все кидал архивом но, архивировал не саму папку MySite, а то что находится в ней, например(C://OpenServer/domeins/MySite/тут сама структура проекта) возможно ли что какие то скрытые системой файлы не добавились в проект? В БД ссылку типа http://localhost заменил на нужную, в конфиге тоже все необходимые изменения провел.

Comment: wp ставит пути до файлов абсолютные, пройдитесь по базе и замените их

Comment: @DaemonHK очень плохой совет. Хотите угробить сериализованные данные, а вместе с ними и сайт? Замену ссылок (не путей до файлов) делать надо, но специализированными программами, например, плагином Duplicator. https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: @KAGGDesign это из-за кол-ва символов в сериализации? Обычно меняются пути только до конфигурационных файлов, а такие данные обычно потом вроде как сами перезаписываются. По крайней мере, проблем никогда не было.

Comment: @DaemonHK править текстовой заменой по дампу базы можно, если только сайт примитивный. Как только сериализованные данные - все. Проблема именно в длине строк, которая указывается явно.

Comment: @DaemonHK давно хочу написать вопрос-ответ на эту тему, часто обсуждается

Comment: @KAGGDesign тогда стоит указать что именно и где нужно поменять, чтобы сайт заработал, хотя, думаю, вы и так это хотите расписать)) Если что, могу помочь с данным вопросом.

Comment: @DaemonHK, воздержись давать советы по ВП. Даже если думаешь, что хорошо знаешь php. у ВП свой мир, его нужно знать. Хорошие php-кодеры, не знающие ВП не редко делают большие ошибки, приводящие к тяжело исправляемым проблемам.

Comment: @SeVlad, wp  я знаю на должном уровне, а голову включать всегда следует, а не делать все на автоматическом режиме

Comment: @DaemonHK я написал - плагин duplicator. Как вариант - вручную править сериализованные данные, высчитывая длину строк )))

Comment: @DaemonHK если бы знал "на должном" - не давал бы советов космической глупости.

Comment: DaemonHK Уважаемый, я правильно понимаю, что когда я в теме сам что то изменил, удалил или добавил новые объекты то, мне потом нужно при переносе все пути ручками заново указывать как это я делал при первой записи? Я просто впервые столкнулся с этим вопросом раньше я просто в базе ссылку с localhost менял на MySite.ru и все норм работало.

Comment: @DaemonHK Уважаемый, я правильно понимаю, что когда я в теме сам что то изменил, удалил или добавил новые объекты то, мне потом нужно при переносе все пути ручками заново указывать как это я делал при первой записи? Я просто впервые столкнулся с этим вопросом раньше я просто в базе ссылку с localhost менял на MySite.ru и все норм работало.

Comment: @vrvInfraSakh, как уже писали выше и в ответе, пути на системные файлы, такие как конфиг, к изображениям в тексте нужно менять самому, либо через рекомендованный плагин, их, на самом деле немного, ну кроме разве что в тексте статей. С остальными путями (сериализованные данные) нужно быть очень осторожным, иногда плагины сами обновляют, иногда нет. Вы вообще смотрели куда стучится сайт на сервере при поиске картинок, например?

Answer (score 1):

Для переноса сайта с одного хостинга на другой и/или при смене  домена нужно использовать плагины миграции. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Или же после импорта родной не изменённой(!!!) базы, не заходя на сайт(**1**) с пом скрипта https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ последовательно исправлять все вхождения путей к файлам, не забывая про возможное экранирование слешей и пр символов.
После путей изменять домен. После, а не до! Ибо домен может содержаться в путях. Домен менять не менее внимательно и осторожно, тк он может содержаться в данных, которые менять не следует.

Это связано с тем, что сам ВП, а больше плагины и темы хранят данные в сериализованных массивах. Ручная правка дампа в блокноте или SQL-запросами в базу их поломает.

(**1**) А не заходя потому, что при обращении к сайту ВП может поменять часть данных и уже безвозвратно всё поломается.